# How to put three different android projects into single 3 tabbed-view android app

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have created three android small formula based calculators (They are working well). Now I want to put those three apps into single android application with three tabs (Tabbed view). And Android Studio, by selecting tab view, is creating the three tabbed view automatically. Now my question is how i can add code of those three apps into each tab of my new app. Please help?

In each code, i have mainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, content_main.xml files.

Comment: you need to convert every activity  (3 in this case) into 3 fragments to used with tabbed activity.good luck

Comment: Have all three apps be modules inside of an Android Studio project. Convert the modules to be library modules. Create another module that serves as the app. Have the app module depend on the three libraries. Change your activities into fragments. In the app, set up your tabs (e.g., `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator) and populate them using the three fragments.

Comment: @CommonWare, please help me with an example. I am completely new to programming. The need to create an app for my filling station, forcing me learn it. I have MainActivity.java which has code for three tabs with view pager. code in that to include code to different tabs:  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           if (position == 0) {
                return new DipToVol();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new VolToDip();
            } else
                return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

        } //it is working. Loading tabs

Comment: My DipToVol.java has the following code : public class DipToVol extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return view;
    } //Here Fragment_main.xml is layout file. Upto here my app is working. I have Calculate and Clear buttons in this code. when i click any of these buttons, app is crashing while  the same buttons were working in my individual calculators.